# Matrix of high rank mod $2$: must it have a large non-singular minor (with disjoint rows and columns)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices

Let $A$ be a $2n$-by-$2n$ matrix with entries in
$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that, for every $2n$-by-$2n$ diagonal
matrix $D$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the matrix $A+D$
has rank $\geq 2n -k$, where $k\geq 0$.

Must there exist an $n$-by-$n$
submatrix $B$ of $A$ with rank $\geq n-k$ and disjoint row and column index sets $I$, $J$ (so that $\{1,2,\dotsc,2n\} = I \sqcup J$)?

(Note that the answer is vacuously "yes" for $k=0$, in that the condition cannot be fulfilled for $k=0$: the determinant is a polynomial on the entries of $D$, and it is easy to show that it must have at least one zero (easy case of the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz, if you wish).)

(Also: obviously, a 0-1 matrix can be interpreted as the adjacency matrix of a directed graph - does that yield anything?)

Comment: I've asked some related questions recently. In brief - over fields of characteristic $\ne 2$, if $A$ is antisymmetric, then already $\text{rank}(A)\geq 2n-k$ implies the existence of a minor of rank $\geq n-k$ (in fact $\geq \lfloor n-k/2\rfloor$ and disjoint rows and columns. If we do not assume that $A$ is antisymmetric, and assume only that $A$ has rank $\geq 2n-k$, there are counterexamples. The condition on all $A+D$ breaks the counterexamples and is also natural for applications.

Comment: you probably mean $\{1,\ldots,2n\}=I\sqcup J$

Comment: condition can not be fulfilled for $k=0$ since the vector $f_0=(1,1,\dots,1)^t$ belongs to kernel of $A+D$ for appropriate $D$ (namely, $D=diag(Af_0)$).

Comment: Yes, and yes, that's an even easier reason!

Comment: Perhaps $D$ such that $A+D$ is the graph Laplacian (of the graph of which $A$ is an adjacency matrix) is of special interest?

Comment: Feel free to experiment with slightly different conditions!

Comment: Do your experiments suggest that the property you want holds?

Comment: Well, the number of possible matrices grows like $2^{4 n^2}$, and I feel that, if there are counterexamples, they occur only for $n\geq 3$. Of course I could take a sample.